# Need to know good inline add/edit and copy grid using Jquery

Tags: php, grid

I need to know which is jQuery table grid is nice using PHP which have facility like inline add/edit,Copy functionality.

I already search kendo UI and Jqgrid but need some one use good jQuery table grid like above.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: i would recommend you to use free-jqgrid (https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then try something and ask again.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try datatable inline edit plugin

Below is the link

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: But i need to copy function as well which store data temp and while click on apply that data should post for insertion.
Any thoughts on this feature ?